# Contact list design suggestion

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm constructing a custom contact list with 5 required fields. It's a bit difficult to fit all 5 in a single row without looking like it's cluttering or doing nested rows which make it hard to distinguish the rows. Here are a couple of designs that I came up with (below). Is there a better way to organize the fields, such as expanding the row when selected to reveal more info, or simply make the row height bigger? Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear what your five fields are. Most important field(s) (e.g. name or contact number) should be at the top in bold style. The second row should contain less important fields, but you need to put enough spaces and style to distinguish them. You should also use ellipsize(...) attribute to contain them within the boundary. If it is important to show the whole string, you may even use third row for any field. Hope this helps.